# Rearranging woocommerce checkout price order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[image]

How to rearrange those table to be like this

-subtotal
-discount (descuento total)
-shipping (envío)
-total

Is there any php code available for that to arrange that?

---

> And again woocommerce coders are there php code to display Price total
> in the table and the shipping in the table then I'll know how to find
> my way through it I have seen for the discount total code though I
> just need for total price and shipping too

---

Thanks

Comment: You will need to change the code in the woocommerce checkout page template to reorder this.

Comment: Now the problem is I can't find the checkout template on my wordpress theme editor dashboard I'm using divi?

Comment: This will be woocommerce template. Check woocommerce plugin folder and cart template. Make sure you do any code changes in the child theme.